# Search and Search &Replace in Visual Studio 2008 everywhere besides comments?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, search

Is there a way to search and eventually search and replace text in Visual Studio but to skip it (not show) if it's commented out (either with // or multi line comments).

Additionally is there a way to skip some file(s) when doing search && replace on whole solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is the name of an identifier, you may right-click on the identifier and select "/Refactor/Rename...", and then make sure "search in comments" is unchecked. This will quickly rename all usage of the identifer.

Answer (score 1):

The [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v6/mztools6.aspx) add-in allows you to do both - exclude comments and select/unselect files to be searched.

Comment: Would it go hand in hand with Resharper?